# "Something needs to be done" vs "something needs doing"

Tags: sentence-construction

There is the sentence "...but there's obviously some work that needs doing." in a video of Oxford Online English.

Why not "... some work that needs to be done."? Is it correct to use "doing" instead?

Comment: Both are idiomatic. But, as this Ngram shows, the latter is far more popular than the former. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+needs+to+be+done%2Cit+needs+doing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20needs%20to%20be%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20needs%20doing%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Mainly British and rather informal. My fence needs painting, my dog needed feeding, my baby will need dressing. Some regional dialects use 'want' instead - my shirt wants washing.

Comment: Maybe not so 'regional' - 'Your hair wants cutting,' said the Hatter. He had been looking at Alice for some time with great curiosity, and this was his first speech. 'You should learn not to make personal remarks,' Alice said with some severity; 'it's very rude. ' - _Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland_ Lewis Carroll (1865)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - In some regional dialects you'll even find constructions like "Some work **needs done**," but this is non-standard and should not be imitated by learners.  Linguists call it the ["needs washed"](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed) construction.